# How do we prove gravity exist?

Tags: gravity

In order to prove gravity in it's basic form, we use a fact like an object released above ground will travel downwards. This I suppose is using the rule of inference where in theory it says There is attraction between two objects hence they travel towards. But in the rule of inference itself, just because result is true, does not mean the hypothesis is true. For example in P -> Q, just because Q was true, P doesn't have to be true. Based on that using objects falling from the sky to prove the existence of gravity isn't correct am I right? It does not disproof, but I am puzzled as to how it can be used to prove.

Comment: Science doesn't attempt to prove _anything_ in that sense.

Comment: It may sound strange at first, but instead of *proving* that P implies Q, we assume P and predict its implications. We then *test* the predictions, in other words, we see if we observe Q. Now, this is in fact unable to prove the validity of P, but if the prediction is not observed and we find that Q is false, then P must be false. After all, P implying Q is tantamount to the negation of Q implying the negation of P. As P survives several tests, we then are lead to believe that in that situations it is a good model to assume P. But it may be falsified later, and the theory gets revisited.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking.  There is the *observed* natural phenomenon that objects *gravitate* which is the metaphysically *given*.  Then there are the mathematical models of the observed phenomenon which can be *disproved* but not *proven*. What then do you mean by "prove gravity"?

Comment: this is definitely a philosophy question, not a physics one, perhaps it would be better received on Philosophy SE

Answer (score 1):

Certainly from P -> Q and Q, we can not infer P.

But if

a)  Q is a conjunction of a great many seemingly unrelated statements (objects fall when we drop them AND the planets follow elliptical orbits around the sun AND the orbit of mercury precesses AND light traveling past a massive object is deflected by a particular amount AND the universe is expanding AND black holes will form AND gravitational waves will be detected)

and

b)  P is, by contrast with Q, a remarkably simple statement and takes a form similar to the form of many other statements that have proved viable in the past

then on Bayesian grounds, it is not unreasonable to attribute a pretty high probability to the hypothesis that P lies not too far from the truth.

Answer (score 1):

You gave an example of $P\rightarrow Q$, but in this case, we mean $P\leftrightarrow Q$.

A simple example of $P\rightarrow Q$ would be saying that the sun goes around because the earth is round. We can say that the sun goes around because the earth is round, but we cannot say that the fact that the sun goes around is a proof that the earth is round, because there are explanations of this phenomenon with the flat-earth theory.

In this case, however, would be $P\leftrightarrow Q$. We conducted an experiment, which in specific, would prove the hypothesis too. Or, to be more accurate, this "theorem" we made, will change overtime, due to more and more accurate measurements being made. For example, as you said for gravity, I'll use the Newton's universal gravitation law.

$$F=G\cfrac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$$

In this equation, we would think that "Oh, nothing's been changed since newton made it", but it **is** changed, and it's the $G$.

Let's look at the [Wikipedia page for the gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant), we all know that $G$ is nearly $6.67\times 10^{-11}$, but in the early ages, it was as inaccurate as $7(\pm1)\times10^{-11}$. Now, we have very accurate values such as $6.67408(31)\times 10^{-11}$.

Please note that, Science is a study which is always prone of change, and **anything** that you believed can change. From old sciences such as Newtonian mechanics, to relatively new sciences such as Quantum mechanics, They're all changing. Differently to that of Mathematics, Physics is a study of reality, thus equations, constants and coefficients change from time to time. So what I can tell you is that equations are getting **made up** reflecting reality, not being **proved.** **explanations of phenomenons** are of proof, but the **equations**, are not.

Answer (score 1):

Scientific reasoning or "proof" is based on [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning), not deductive reasoning.

If I observe one thousand black crows and no white crows then deductive reasoning only allows me to conclude that "some crows are black". But inductive reasoning allows me to conclude with a high degree of confidence that "all crows are black".

If I then observe a single white crow then I would look carefully for an explanation for this unexpected observation. I might then modify my inductive conclusion to "all crows are black unless they have a genetic mutation" or "all crows are black unless they have fallen into a pot of white paint".

Comment: There is a difference in an abstract concept like gravity which you cannot feel, touch etc vs something like what you have mentioned (Crows). May be that's better applied in medicinal sciences.

Comment: @xelber All science is based on inductive reasoning from observations and experimental results. An abstract concept such as Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation is an explanation for some of those observations. You cannot "prove" that a model is a correct explanation - you can only show that it is consistent with observations so far. Newton's Law was a successful model at first, but eventually new observations (e.g. the precession of Mercury's orbit and the deflection of light by the Sun) showed that Newtonian gravitation was not correct, and it was replaced with General Relativity.

Comment: I agree its a model explaining the observation as well, which is something I wanted to get to. Unfortunately some take it as absolute truth which negate the very essence of science and take it as a religion.